# Dynamically create a class which derived from an ABC class

Tags: python, mongodb

I am using PyMongo custom bson encoder. Because the encoder cannot be inherited, it needs to be created for every class, so I want to dynamically create an encoder for it.

The problem is that the base encoder (`TypeEncoder`) is created from ABC class. When I was trying to create the class using this code:

```
from bson.codec_options import TypeEncoder

cls_encoder = type(f"Flag{cls.__name__}Encoder", 
                   (TypeEncoder,),
                   {"transform_python": lambda self, value: value.code,
                    "python_type": property(lambda self: cls)})
```

The result will be

```
>> isinstance(cls_encoder, TypeEncoder)
False
>> type(cls_encoder)
<class 'abc.FlagAutoReplyContentTypeEncoder'>
>> super(cls_encoder)
<super: <class 'FlagAutoReplyContentTypeEncoder'>, NULL>
```

The expected result should be

```
>> isinstance(cls_encoder, TypeEncoder)
True
```

Note: the `cls` variable will be an Enum
Note: `python_type` is an `abstractproperty`; `transform_python` is a function which accepts the value in the type of `python_type` and returns something which [type is valid for bson serialization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/).

---

I have tried this:

```
class FlagBsonEncoder(TypeEncoder):
    def transform_python(self, value):
        return value.code

cls_encoder = type(f"Flag{cls.__name__}Encoder", 
                   (FlagBsonEncoder,),
                   {"python_type": property(lambda self: cls)})
```

But still the same result:

```
>> isinstance(cls_encoder, TypeEncoder)
False
```

---

Here is the official example of how to use custom type encoding:
http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/codec_options.html
http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/custom_type.html#custom-type-type-codec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand what `isinstance` does, I think.

`isinstance(cls_encoder, TypeEncoder)` asks if the *class object* `cls_encoder` is an instance of `TypeEncoder`. Of course it is not - it is a *type*!

What you want is `isinstance(cls_encoder(), TypeEncoder)`, which asks if an instance of `cls_encoder` is also an instance of `TypeEncoder`, which of course must be true.

If you want to check if the class `cls_encoder` is a *subclass* of `TypeEncoder`, you can use `issubclass(cls_encoder, TypeEncoder)`.

Comment: You're right lol, I forgot to instantiate to test it. Thanks for the help! :D

Comment: @ReblochonMasque thanks for the tips. I accepted this answer but cannot upvote because of the lacking reputation.

Comment: Good on you, thank you! Now your rep should be sufficient to upvote.

Comment: Still need 2 hahaha, will try to remember to upvote when I got 15 and go back here